# What is SwapRouter in Uniswap v3?

Tags: contract-development, erc-20, contract-invocation, uniswap

I am trying to find any information about the SwapRouter contract in Uniswap V3. I have tried searching on Web and docs, but nothing meaningful shows up. Based on my general understanding of Uniswap, it seems like an orchestrator that is responsible for swapping one ERC 20 token into another, i.e. ERC 20 token 1 -> ETH -> ERC 20 token 2. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The swapRouter is the contract doing, quoting Uniswap comments,  "important verification" (in terms of amounts, slippage, etc) and, novelty of Uniswap V3, handling the swap callback which is responsible to verify the authenticity of the pool as well as sending the tokenIn on your behalf (see the official doc on how to use it : https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/reference/periphery/SwapRouter)
The swapRouter will, hence the name, "organise" multiroute swaps too (hopping from pool to pool).

The pool is the contract doing the actual "give me x and I let you receive y".

You can find the swapRouter on mainnet here : https://etherscan.io/address/0xe592427a0aece92de3edee1f18e0157c05861564